# Is it fine to call request.getAttribute() after session.invalidate()

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

I have an application that calls the following HttpServletRequest and Session methods in sequence:

- `request.setAttribute("name", "strVal");` in some servlet A.
  `session.invalidate();` in a filter's doAfter method.
  `request.getAttribute("name");` in a JSP.

Is it fine to call request.getAttribute() after the session is invalidated and why/why not?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is fine. **Request** scope and **Session** scopes are different. Invalidating session does not affect the request scope.

Request scope lasts for a request.
Session Scope lasts for a user session.

[Java EE scopes](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjbbk.html)

Answer (score 0):

It is fine. They are different scopes having different lifecycles.